# populate gridview on dropdownlist indexchanged

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

i have gridview which populate date from database i want to change seclected data on dropdown SelectedIndexChanged when i select the first index it selected data from database when i chang selections it get another data try this code  but nosense this is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }

 private void BindData()
    {
        if (ddlTguidedit.SelectedIndex==0)
        {
            string strQuery = "SELECT [Pdfid],[Arpdf_name],[Arpdf_des],[pdf_date] FROM [books_alaa].[dbo].[Tbl_uploadpdf]";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            string strQuery = " SELECT Pdfid, Enpdf_name AS Arpdf_name, Enpdf_des AS Arpdf_des, pdf_url, pdf_date FROM Tbl_uploadpdf";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

 protected void ddlTguidedit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlTguidedit.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            string strQuery = "SELECT [Pdfid],[Arpdf_name],[Arpdf_des],[pdf_date] FROM [books_alaa].[dbo].[Tbl_uploadpdf]";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            string strQuery = " SELECT Pdfid, Enpdf_name AS Arpdf_name, Enpdf_des AS Arpdf_des, pdf_url, pdf_date FROM Tbl_uploadpdf";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

why it doesnt work ??

Comment: What do you mean by `select the first index`? Do you select the first (top) item in the DropDownList or the item at index 1 in the DropDownList? They are different and judging by your code, would return different columns.

Comment: in dropdownlist i have two choise arbic as avlue 1 and english as value 2  i need to to select data from database depend on chosie arabic or english

Comment: Ok, so what isn't working?

Comment: when i select arabic or english the grid still have the same data without change

Answer (score 0):

Remove BindData() from `!IsPostBack()`. You are loading the grid data on DropDownList `SelectedIndexChanged`. There is no need of BindData() function to be in `!IsPostBack()`. BindData() function always loads no matter at what index the DropDownList is, it will always take the index as 0.

Comment: nothing happened itis still  retrive default index as 0